# Почему алгоритм работающий за O(n) не всегда быстрее второго за O(n^2)?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Срезали на тесте на этом вопросе. Не могу понять, что не так, я уверен что правильно ответил

Вопрос звучит так

> Первый алгоритм работает за O(n), второй за O(n^2). Выберите верное утверждение
>
> 1 - При достаточно маленьких n второй будет работать быстрее
> 2 - Первый всегда быстрее второго
> 3 - Второй всегда быстрее первого
> 4 - При достаточно больших n первый будет работать быстрее

Я выбрал **Первый всегда быстрее второго**

Есть цикл, а есть цикл в цикле. Поэтому первый всегда быстрее. Почему я не прав?

Comment: Потому что О() — это **асимптотические** зависимости...

Comment: 4 ответ выглядит достаточно нормально. Достаточно нарисовать два графика.

Comment: Про маленькие n ничего однозначного сказать нельзя, потому что одна итерация второго алгоритма может оказаться быстрее, чем одна итерация первого алгоритма, и тогда второй алгоритм может оказаться быстрее (а может и не оказаться, как повезёт). Но рано или поздно найдётся такое число n, при котором даже быстрых итераций второго алгоритма окажется слишком много и первый алгоритм окажется быстрее. Поэтому ответ 4 выглядит наиболее правдоподобным

Comment: @andreymal вопрос чисто теоретический, значит бритвой Оккама отрезаем все *"может оказаться быстрее (а может и не оказаться, как повезёт"*.

Comment: @Kromster не отрезаем, вы в своём ответе написали то же самое, только другими словами

Comment: @andreymal специально для вас хотел уточнить про бритву

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала покажу почему вы неправы про

> **Первый всегда быстрее второго**

Пускай зависимость количества шагов первого алгоритма от размера входных данных выражается формулой `f(n)=3*n`, а для второго - `g(n)=n^2`.

Обратите внимание, что для всех `n<3` `f(n) > g(n)`, это видно хотя бы из графиков:

[image: графики]

т.е. второй алгоритм будет делать меньше шагов, а значит работать быстрее, когда данных мало (`n<3`). При этом сложность первого алгоритма `O(n)`, а второго `O(n^2)`. Это контрпример, который показывает почему неверно утверждение, что алгоритм со сложностью `O(n)` всегда быстрее алгоритма со сложностью `O(n^2)`.

Вероятно, нужно пояснить, что означает, что алгоритм имеет сложность `O(n)` или `O(n^2)` ну и в общем случае `O(f(n))`, где `f(n)` - некая функция.

Общее определение такое:

> Алгоритм имеет сложность `O(f(n))`, если существуют такие числа `C` и `N`, что для количества шагов алгоритма (определяемое формулой `g(n)`) выполняется условие, что для каждого `n>N: g(n) <= C*f(n)`

Начну с примера для первого алгоритма, у которого количество шагов определяется по формуле `k(n)=3*n`. Если мы возьмем `C=3 и N=1`, то получаем, что для любого `n>1` выполняется `3*n <= 3*n`, а значит по определению алгоритм имеет сложность `O(n)`. Тут `f(n)=n` и `g(n)=3*n`.

Answer (score 2):

- 1 - *При достаточно маленьких n второй будет работать быстрее* - при достаточно маленьком `n` разница между `O(n)` и `O(n^2)` будет минимальна и ничего определённого сказать нельзя про то, какой алгоритм будет работать быстрее
- 2 - *Первый всегда быстрее второго* - вот как-раз не всегда, а см. выше
- 3 - *Второй всегда быстрее первого* - нет, конечно
- 4 - *При достаточно больших n первый будет работать быстрее* - а вот это вполне похоже на суть разницы `O(n)` и `O(n^2)`

Comment: Первое утверждение нехорошее, про разницу ничего нельзя сказать, она зависит от констант.

Answer (score 1):

Можем подойти с точки зрения чистой теории, формально, **без привлечения новых сущностей** - `n <= n^2`:

1 - *"При достаточно маленьких n второй будет работать быстрее"* - очевидно **нет**, т.к. у нас нет никакой информации о каких-либо иных компонентах дающих вклад в скорость выполнения, кроме сложности.
2 - *"Первый всегда быстрее второго"* - **нет**, Т.к. при n=1 оба будут одинаковыми.
3 - *"Второй всегда быстрее первого"* - очевидно **нет**.
4 - *"При достаточно больших n первый будет работать быстрее"* - очевидно **да**.